# Scroll View User Interaction Disabled Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a swift project, and I created the following layout structure:

[image: Story board layout]

And it looks like this:

[image: the layout in the simulator]

Everything's fine, BUT: I don't know why the scroll view is not working. And I can't do user interaction besides the play button at the bottom.

Here is my swift file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+300)
}
```

What should I do? 
I have the same problem on another view, where I have a WebView as the main part of the screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you disabled interaction on any of the superviews? Use the layout debugger to check what view in the hierachy has the disabled interaction. Also, you should not set the content size like this. Have autolayout pin the content view to the scrolviews edges and the scrollview will adjust the size automatically.

Comment: Don't explicitly set `.contentSize` --- use constraints and let auto-layout handle it.

Comment: DonMag is right. Or you try setting the contentSize in the viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Agree with both previous comments, another thing you can check in the layout debugger is that you don't have another view with clear color on top of everything, maybe this is what's preventing the scrollView to work

Comment: Everything looks to me normal at View Debugger. https://prnt.sc/ofv5by
The button is working. so I have no idea why there is no interaction on scroll view.

Comment: Can you please show the auto layout constraints that you did